# How to use locationListener in android fragment

Tags: android, google-maps, android-fragments

I want to use locationListener in my android fragment. But I am getting an error. My code is in below.

```
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    LocationListener locationListener = new LocationListener() {
        @Override
        public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {

        }
    };

    locationManager = (LocationManager) getActivity().getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);
    if (locationManager.isProviderEnabled(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER)) {
        locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER, 2000, 1, locationListener);
    } 
    else {

    }
}
```

I am getting this error.

> Can't resolve method requestLocationUpdates

Comment: do you have compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-location:10.2.4' in your gradle?

Comment: Yes........................

Comment: can you post your import statement

Comment: See my answer, that will solve your problem 100%

Comment: Check out this for current best practices: Gives an example with LocationListener https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/architecture/lifecycle.html

Answer (score 0):

Create this class:

```
public class GetCurrentLocation implements
            ConnectionCallbacks, OnConnectionFailedListener, LocationListener {

        private static final String TAG = "location-updates-sample";
        public static final long UPDATE_INTERVAL_IN_MILLISECONDS = 0;
        public static final long FASTEST_UPDATE_INTERVAL_IN_MILLISECONDS =
                UPDATE_INTERVAL_IN_MILLISECONDS / 2;
        private final String REQUESTING_LOCATION_UPDATES_KEY = "requesting-location-updates-key";
        private final String LOCATION_KEY = "location-key";
        private final String LAST_UPDATED_TIME_STRING_KEY = "last-updated-time-string-key";
        private GoogleApiClient mGoogleApiClient;
        private LocationRequest mLocationRequest;

        private Context mContext;
        private getLocation mGetCurrentLocation;

        public GetCurrentLocation(Context context) {
            mContext = context;

            buildGoogleApiClient();
        }

        private synchronized void buildGoogleApiClient() {
            Log.i(TAG, "Building GoogleApiClient");
            mGoogleApiClient = new GoogleApiClient.Builder(mContext)
                    .addConnectionCallbacks(this)
                    .addOnConnectionFailedListener(this)
                    .addApi(LocationServices.API)
                    .build();
            createLocationRequest();
        }

        public interface getLocation{
            public void onLocationChanged(Location location);
        }

        public void startGettingLocation(getLocation location) {
            mGetCurrentLocation = location;
            connect();
        }

        public void stopGettingLocation() {
            stopLocationUpdates();
            disconnect();
        }

        private void createLocationRequest() {
            mLocationRequest = new LocationRequest();
            mLocationRequest.setInterval(UPDATE_INTERVAL_IN_MILLISECONDS);
            mLocationRequest.setFastestInterval(FASTEST_UPDATE_INTERVAL_IN_MILLISECONDS);
            mLocationRequest.setPriority(LocationRequest.PRIORITY_HIGH_ACCURACY);
        }

        private void startLocationUpdates() {
            if (mGoogleApiClient.isConnected()) {
                LocationServices.FusedLocationApi.requestLocationUpdates(
                        mGoogleApiClient, mLocationRequest, this);
            }
        }
    private void stopLocationUpdates() {
        LocationServices.FusedLocationApi.removeLocationUpdates(mGoogleApiClient, this);
    }



    private void connect() {
        mGoogleApiClient.connect();
    }

    private void disconnect() {
        if (mGoogleApiClient.isConnected()) {
            mGoogleApiClient.disconnect();
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onConnected(Bundle connectionHint) {
        Log.i(TAG, "Connected to GoogleApiClient");
        startLocationUpdates();

    }

    @Override
    public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {
        mGetCurrentLocation.onLocationChanged(location);
    }

    @Override
    public void onConnectionSuspended(int cause) {
        Log.i(TAG, "Connection suspended");
        mGoogleApiClient.connect();
    }

    @Override
    public void onConnectionFailed(ConnectionResult result) {
        Log.i(TAG, "Connection failed: ConnectionResult.getErrorCode() = " + result.getErrorCode());
    }
}
```

In your fragment class:

```
private GetCurrentLocation mListen;
mListen = new GetCurrentLocation(this);
            mListen.startGettingLocation(new GetCurrentLocation.getLocation() {
                @Override
                public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {
                   // Here is my working with location object
                }

            });
```

make sure you have added latest googleplayservice library in your gradle file.

Answer (score 0):

Implement all the methods of `LocationListener`

```
@Override
        public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                                 Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            TextView textView = new TextView(getActivity());
            textView.setText(R.string.hello_blank_fragment);

            LocationManager locationManager = (LocationManager) getActivity().getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);
            if (locationManager.isProviderEnabled(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER)) {
                if (new Utility().checkAndGrantPermission(getActivity(), Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION, 101, "your custom message"))
                    locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER, 2000, 1, locationListener);
            }

            return textView;
        }
```

Outside from `onCreate`

```
 LocationListener locationListener = new LocationListener() {
        @Override
        public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {
                  //Todo your code
        }

        @Override
        public void onStatusChanged(String provider, int status, Bundle extras) {
                      //Todo your code
        }

        @Override
        public void onProviderEnabled(String provider) {
                      //Todo your code
        }

        @Override
        public void onProviderDisabled(String provider) {
                      //Todo your code
        }
    };
```

And the `checkAndGrantPermission` method is

```
public boolean checkAndGrantPermission(final Context context, final String permissionString, final int requestCode, String permissoinTypeMessage)
    {
        int currentAPIVersion = Build.VERSION.SDK_INT;
        if(currentAPIVersion>=android.os.Build.VERSION_CODES.M)
        {
            if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(context, permissionString) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {

                if (ActivityCompat.shouldShowRequestPermissionRationale((Activity) context, permissionString)) {
                    // your custom dialog screen when user deny permission
                } else {
                    ActivityCompat.requestPermissions((Activity) context, new String[]{permissionString}, requestCode);
                }
                return false;
            } else {
                return true;
            }
        } else {
            return true;
        }
    }
```

In Activity override `onRequestPermissionsResult`

```
 @Override
    public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, @NonNull String[] permissions, @NonNull int[] grantResults) {
        super.onRequestPermissionsResult(requestCode, permissions, grantResults);

        if (requestCode == 101) {
            yourFragmentInstance.onRequestPermissionsResult(requestCode,permissions,grantResults);
        }
    }
```

In Your Framgent override `onRequestPermissionsResult`

```
 @Override
    public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, @NonNull String[] permissions, @NonNull int[] grantResults) {
        super.onRequestPermissionsResult(requestCode, permissions, grantResults);

        if (requestCode == 101) {

            if (requestCode == AppConstants.runtimePermissionCode) {
                if (permissions[0].equals(Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION) && grantResults[0] == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                    locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER, 2000, 1, locationListener);
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Got your issue.

You have used Location listener from

```
com.google.android.gms.location.LocationListener;
```

You have to import LocationListener from

```
android.location.Location;
```

Try this one:

```
locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER, 2000, 1, new android.location.LocationListener() {
            @Override
            public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {

            }

            @Override
            public void onStatusChanged(String provider, int status, Bundle extras) {

            }

            @Override
            public void onProviderEnabled(String provider) {

            }

            @Override
            public void onProviderDisabled(String provider) {

            }
        });
```

Hope it helps:)